# MySQL generates nested JSON objects

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I am trying to generate nested JSON objects from many_to_many relationships. I am trying to find the JSON pattern below.

```
    [
  {
   "user_id": 151,
   "user_name": “Sam123”,
   "role_desc": [“Power_User”]
   
  },
  {
   "user_id": 152,
   "user_name": “John999”,
   "role_desc": ["Admin", "Power_User"]
   
  }
}
```

I tried combined JSON functions as follows, but the result differed from what I required.

```
SET @result = JSON_OBJECT('result,0,'data ',(SELECT 
              JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(             
              'user_id',user_tbl.user_id,
              ‘user_name’, user_tbl.user_name,
              'role_desc',app_role_tbl.role_desc)) 
              FROM user_tbl
INNER JOIN user_role ON user_tbl.user_id = user_role.user_id
INNER JOIN app_role_tbl ON user_role.role_id = app_role_tbl.role_id ));
```

The result comes with a duplicate user_id, and each user_id had two rows for each role a row.

```
SET @result = JSON_OBJECT('result,0,'data ',(SELECT 
                         JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(                      
                         'user_id',user_tbl.user_id,
                         ‘user_name’, user_tbl.user_name,
              'role_desc',JSON_ARRAYAGG(app_role_tbl.role_desc))) 
              FROM user_tbl
INNER JOIN user_role ON user_tbl.user_id = user_role.user_id
INNER JOIN app_role_tbl ON user_role.role_id = app_role_tbl.role_id ));
```

With this SQL query and those JSON functions, I get an error

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You should probably use a group by somewhere along the way. Hard to say without knowing the structure and seeing some sample data.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: When pinned down & clearly expressed this will be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are way over-complicating it.  You want one object per user, with multiple roles in an array, so you must group by user and form that object.  Dealing with a user with no roles is a little tricky if you don't want `[null]`.  (If you are doing an inner join, not left join, you can omit the case and just use json_arrayagg.)

```
select
  json_object(
    'user_id',user_tbl.user_id,
    'user_name',user_tbl.user_name,
    'role_desc',
      case
        when count(app_role_tbl.role_desc) then json_arrayagg(app_role_tbl.role_desc)
        else json_array()
      end
  ) user
from user_tbl
left join user_role using (user_id)
left join app_role_tbl using (role_id)
group by user_tbl.user_id
```

That produces one json object per user; if you want the server to combine all of those into a json array, just put that in a subquery:

```
select json_arrayagg(user)
from (
  select
    json_object(
      'user_id',user_tbl.user_id,
      'user_name',user_tbl.user_name,
      'role_desc',
        case
          when count(app_role_tbl.role_desc) then json_arrayagg(app_role_tbl.role_desc)
          else json_array()
        end
    ) user
  from user_tbl
  left join user_role using (user_id)
  left join app_role_tbl using (role_id)
  group by user_tbl.user_id
) users;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mPatGrhS)