# How can I store and retrieve invoices in mySQL database

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, phpmyadmin, invoice

I am building an application for business management. I have gotten to the point where I would like to design the quotation and invoices part of the system. I am having trouble to figure out what is the best way to store this data.

One invoice would have multiple items being invoiced and the same goes to one quotation having multiple items being quoted. What is the best approach to use to design the tables in the database for these.

My initial thought was to have one table for invoice that would have the invoice number, client ID, paid field etc and another table that would have the item number, description, unit price, tax etc and the retrieve them separately.

However, I would like to receive the data as follows:

```
{
  "Invoice No": ***,
  "Client Name": ***,
  "Date": ***,
  "Order No": ***,
  "Deliver Note No": ***,
  "Details":{
              [
               "Item No": 1,
               "Description": ***,
               "Quantity": ***,
               "Unit Price": ***,
              ],
              [
               "Item No": 2,
               "Description": ***,
               "Quantity": ***,
               "Unit Price": ***,
              ]
                } 
}
```

The above is just sample just to give an idea of what I am expecting.

How can I design my database and fetch data so that I get such a result from my API?

Comment: You've got two questions here. The database layout is a matter of opinion, although I'd say you're plan is a good start. Producing the JSON format could possibly be done in MySQL, but might be easier in PHP. Ask separately about that.

Comment: Details looks like you mean to be an array of objects, not an object containing arrays.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75596878/17389 is an example of how you would read invoices with an array of invoice lines included

Comment: @ysth yes you are right. I am looking for an array of objects. That is the challenge I am facing how I can structure my  tables to get that. I have gone through the link you have sent and I am still not clear. Will you please elaborate more and maybe help me figure an outline

Comment: I will try to, if you provide some create table statements for your invoice and invoice items tables and sample data and expected results for that sample data.  but like TP says, you are asking two questions in one here; worry more about a database design that makes sense and less about how to get specific output out of it